# IE8+ what is the best way to communicate with a same domain opener <-> tabs? postMessage doesn't work, opener.f() & loc.href = FAIL

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, postmessage

I am creating a sign-in flow for a bookmarklet and as I want to avoid doing a redirect flow because of several other complications that it would incur. As a result I am looking for a way to communicate between tabs or a popup of the same domain and an inner iFrame that serves as a window.opener in the new tab or popup.

In other browsers this can be accomplished by window.opener.postMessage, but in IE8+ this is not allowed between windows, only between iFrames, so of course in typical fashion IE needs to be dealt with on a special basis because they can't follow standards or expected behavior.

In several other attempts I have tried various approaches, and I may still try easyXDM, but I was hoping to use a lighter weight piece of code than to include another library into a bookmarklet, which i eventually want to compress via google's closure compressor.

I have tried:
`window.opener.postMessage()` - does not work in IE8 between tabs

`window.opener.location.href` - does not work reliably

`window.opener.someFunction()` - does not work on all functions? why?

what is kinda working right now is by setting the `localStorage.authToken` in the child window/tab and then in the parent/opener have a
`setInterval(function(){checkToken(localStorate.authToken)},3000);`

**UPDATE**
I found a reasonable solution in doing this
http://www.sfpeter.com/2008/03/communication-between-browser-windows-with-jquery-my-new-plugin/

This approach from SFPeter, sets up a small hidden form on each page and then uses event messages for each one.  It works for same domain requests and it happens to work between windows and tabs on IE8+.  It does seem to issue a click event on the body as part of the passing, which might need to be ignored in some circumstances.

Comment: If using localStorage is an option for you, then there is no need to poll localStorage to see if something changed, just attach an  event handler to the "storage" event and it will get fired when something changes: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#storage-event. The best thing is -- the event is fired only on same-origin windows which did *not* initiate the change in localStorage (so, if window A changes localStorage, it will not get the event, but window B on the same origin will, if it is listening). So, it's basically a system you can use for message-oriented communication.

Comment: @IvanZuzak, I think this works fine in FF and Chrome, but not in IE8 between tabs.  I could try it out later.

Comment: it _should_ work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452816/does-ie8-out-of-the-box-have-support-for-localstorage. let me know :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to propagate opener variable across page navigation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896743/best-way-to-propagate-opener-variable-across-page-navigation)